# <ContentControl><ContentPresenter/></ContentControl>?

Tags: wpf

I am looking at someone's control template and wherever this template needs to include content, it uses:

```
<ContentControl>
   <ContentPresenter />
</ContentControl>
```

Why not use just `<ContentPresenter />`? Is there any reason why it needs to be wrapped in ContentControl?

Thanks

konstantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason why it needs to be wrapped in ContentControl?

It doesn't need to. Doing this is useless, you only need to use `<ContentPresenter />` in a `ControlTemplate`